# Paypal sandbox blocking transactions

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating Paypal into my website and I am currently testing it using 2 sandbox accounts (1 merchant and 1 buyer). I have tried about 30 transactions between them and it is all working but just now, Paypal has blocked the transactions with the error `PimpAbort with return code 4002`. I searched online and it seems this error occurs if Paypal decides this to be a risky transaction, most likely because I keep sending money from the same buyer account to the merchant account. I want to ask it is possible to change some settings so that I disable this checking? Or is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an issue on PayPal's end. I've had all my sandbox transactions end with that error yesterday and today.